# Calculator program in ruby, taking "2+3" and giving output 6, issues with more than 2 digit numbers

Tags: ruby

First post, excuse if I break any etiquette. I am beginning, so this might be simple.

Trying to code in ruby, a calculator, where user inputs arithmetic sentence (only binary, PEMDAS/BIDMAS will do later) and the answer comes out.

Here is my code, by only works for single digit numbers.

```
class Calculator

  def initializer (a,b)
    @a = a,
    @b = b
  end

  def add(a, b)
      a+b
  end

  def subtract(a, b)
    a-b
  end

  def multiply(a,b)
    a*b
  end

  def divide (a,b)
    a/b
  end

  def powers (a,b)
    a**b
  end

 end

puts "Enter an expression to be evaluated"
a = gets.chomp.gsub(/\s+/, "") 

puts case a[1]

when "+"
    "#{a[0]} + #{a[2]} = #{Calculator.new.add(a[0].to_f,a[2].to_f)}"
when "-"
    "#{a[0]} - #{a[2]} = #{Calculator.new.subtract(a[0].to_f,a[2].to_f)}"
when "*" || "x" || "X"
    "#{a[0]} x #{a[2]} = #{Calculator.new.multiply(a[0].to_f,a[2].to_f)}"
when "/"
    "#{a[0]} / #{a[2]} = #{Calculator.new.divide(a[0].to_f,a[2].to_f)}"
when "^"
    "#{a[0]} to the power #{a[2]} = #Calculator.new.powers(a[0].to_f,a[2].to_f)}"
else
    "Not valid"
end
```

I was thinking of trying to split a string like "234+342" (234 and 342 can be any sized length numbers) into an array such as ["234","+","342"].

But I am stuck on how to do this??? Or is there another way??

Help will be appreciated, just a personal challenge.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions on this site are generally expected to have a clearly defined problem, not be general debugging requests. If you would like to ask how to split a string, I recommend searching for an answer before asking. Otherwise please edit your question to remove extraneous  information and clarify your question.

Comment: Split the array along the + or - or * or whatever instead of `gsub`ing it out. That way, you have a two-element array that you can operate on.

Answer (score 1):

As you already realized the issue is with the way you are carrying operations over input string.

The simplest way to proceed can be to ask users for two numbers and then ask them to enter the operation needed. Something like:

```
puts "Enter first number"
a = gets.chomp
puts "Enter second number"
b = gets.chomp
puts "Enter required operation [+, -, *, /]"
c = gets.chomp
```

You can do this all in one shot too, the way you are already trying, however I would advice against it as you never know what user will enter. Eg:

```
puts "Enter an expression to be evaluated"
a = gets.chomp # user enters: 123 + 457
# => "123 + 457"
```

Now extracting number:

```
numbers = a.scan(/\d+/)
#=> ["123", "457"]
operator = a[/\W+/]
#=> " + "
```

You can then proceed with your switch case.